# How to replace function with a concatenate function in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, lambda, replace, jupyter-notebook

I have a column heading in Excel file for stages, and another column is AI80010_6 like below:

```
Stages     Ai80010_6
1          Ai80010_6.cardop.S1
2          Ai80010_6.cardop.XX
2          Ai80010_6.cardop.S2
2          Ai80010_6.fstmor.XX
2          A120300_5.cardop.S2
2          A120300_5.cardop.XX
```

Expected result should be like below:

```
   Stages       Ai80010_6                  output
     1          Ai80010_6.cardop.S1         Ai80010_6.cardop.S1
     2          Ai80010_6.cardop.XX         Ai80010_6.cardop.S2 
     2          Ai80010_6.cardop.S2         Ai80010_6.cardop.S2
     2          Ai80010_6.fstmor.XX         Ai80010_6.fstmor.S2
     2          A120300_5.cardop.S2         A120300_5.cardop.S2
     2          A120300_5.cardop.XX         A120300_5.cardop.S2
```

How can I get the expected output in Jupyter Notebook with Pandas?

I am new to Python coding.

Answer (score 0):

[`rsplit`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html), use a [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) with the stage and combine again:

```
tmp = df['Ai80010_6'].str.rsplit('.', n=1, expand=True)

df['output'] = tmp[0]+'.'+tmp[1].mask(tmp[1].eq('XX'),
                                      'S'+df['Stages'].astype(str))
```

Alternatively, just overwrite the stage:

```
df['output'] = (df['Ai80010_6'].str.extract(r'(.*\.)[^.]*$', expand=False)
                +'S'+df['Stages'].astype(str)
                )
```

Output:

```
   Stages            Ai80010_6               output
0       1  Ai80010_6.cardop.S1  Ai80010_6.cardop.S1
1       2  Ai80010_6.cardop.XX  Ai80010_6.cardop.S1
2       2  Ai80010_6.cardop.S2  Ai80010_6.cardop.S2
3       2  Ai80010_6.fstmor.XX  Ai80010_6.fstmor.S2
4       2  A120300_5.cardop.S2  A120300_5.cardop.S2
5       2  A120300_5.cardop.XX  A120300_5.cardop.S2
```

Comment: It looks like OP wanted the second line to end with `S2`, not `S1`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
df['output'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Ai80010_6'].replace('XX', f'S{x["Stages"]}') , axis=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Stages            Ai80010_6               output
0       1  Ai80010_6.cardop.S1  Ai80010_6.cardop.S1
1       2  Ai80010_6.cardop.XX  Ai80010_6.cardop.S2
2       2  Ai80010_6.cardop.S2  Ai80010_6.cardop.S2
3       2  Ai80010_6.fstmor.XX  Ai80010_6.fstmor.S2
4       2  A120300_5.cardop.S2  A120300_5.cardop.S2
5       2  A120300_5.cardop.XX  A120300_5.cardop.S2
```